# Magento Region names contains special characters are displayed as null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento-1.7

I have used Magento Venedor theme.  The state name contains special characters are displayed as null in checkout page and manual order creation in magento admin panel.  The checkout page view source is like that

```
"188":{"code":"07","name":null},
"189":{"code":"08","name":"Ardennes"},
"190":{"code":"09","name":null},
"191":{"code":"10","name":"Aube"}
```

For 188 - the region name is Ardèche
for 189 - the region name is Ariège

Any idea about this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Go to magento root & in the .htaccess file add

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

If you still have problems, also uncomment this line:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Hope this will help you.

Regards,

Mirza Shakir